# can't escape dot (.) at my mod_rewrite code

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i need to transform following address of my site: `http://mysite.com/do.php?id=123.W456/789` into `http://mysite.com/123.W456/789`

i've almost got succeed in this noble purpose with following .htaccess file

`DirectoryIndex mysite.php`

`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\/&#46;]+)?$ mysite.php?id=$1 [L]`

where `&#46;` is a code of `.` (dot) character

it goes cool with such url string `http://mysite.com/123W456/789` (i.e rewrites it to `http://mysite.com/do.php?id=123W456/789`)

but DOESN'T rewrite url string with dot character - `http://mysite.com/123.W456/789`

can anybody help?

Answer (score 4):

We use `\.` to escape the dot character in an htaccess file, not the HTML entity for it. Using the HTML entity would make it think that you are allowing the `&`, `#`, and `;` characters rather than the `.` character.

Comment: Then you have something else wrong, try checking your Apache error log.

Comment: when i use `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\/\.]+)?$ mysite.php?id=$1` and than echo `$_GET['id']` i get `mysite.php`

Comment: Obviously your rewrite rule is going to match virtually everything if you're allowing all alphanumeric characters, slashes, and dots. You really should be more specific and use something like `mysite.com/id/123.W456/789`. What was the error that Apache gave you?

Comment: `[Wed Oct 19 22:42:28 2011] [error] [client 87.252.227.84] File does not exist: /var/www/admin/data/www/site.com/10fhsdert, referer: http://site.com/10fhsdert/sad`

-without dot

Comment: `[Wed Oct 19 22:43:28 2011] [error] [client 87.252.227.84] File does not exist: /var/www/admin/data/www/site.com/10fhsdert`

- with dot after 10fhsdert

Comment: Hmmm, if it's rewriting the path correctly then it shouldn't be sending any error. When you go to one with only a `/` it does take you to mysite.php? And the `$_GET['id']` says mysite.php as well?

Comment: `$_GET['id']` says mysite.php only when i use `.`, when i use `/` - `$_GET['id']` says `sfsd/asdafs/asf`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4396/discussion-between-drdarwin-and-animuson)